# Using Contains method with custom objects

Tags: c#

If I have a class like this:

```
public class ContractSpecialtyInfo
{
    public string Sequence { get; set; }
    public string Specialty { get; set; }
    public string Taxonomy { get; set; }
}
```

and then a list of its objects like this in some class:

```
public List<ContractSpecialtyInfo> SpecialtyInfo { get; set; }
```

and then somewhere in the program I retrieve some values for those three properties and create an object out of it, for example:  ContractSpecialtyInfo item = new ContractSpecialtyInfo { ... some values ... }

Now will `C#` be able to tell me the answer to something like:

```
if(SpecialtyInfo.Contains(item))
```

or do I need to help him?  How?  **Basically** I am asking does `Contain` method work on a list if custom objects? or it just works with simple data types like `string`, `int`, etc... and if it doesn't work then what should I do and how?

Comment: [MSDN: List<T>.Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) have you looked at this link for MSDN documentation

Comment: Per the documentation of [List.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) - "This method determines equality by using the default equality comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the IEquatable<T>.Equals method for T (the type of values in the list)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override `Equals` or implement [`IEquatable<ContractSpecialtyInfo>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190(v=vs.110).aspx) to make [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) not only compare references. Or use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb337697(v=vs.100).aspx) and specify how yo want to compare them:

```
bool contains = SpecialtyInfo
   .Any(s => s.Sequence  == item.Sequence 
          && s.Specialty == item.Specialty 
          && s.Taxonomy  == item.Taxonomy);
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, you always answer my questions just right to the point that I need.

Comment: oh interesting, so in your Any() example I don't even need to implement an interface, right? Just use it like that to compare the values of the object I have at hand with all possible objects that might be in the LIST ?

Comment: @ConfusedSleepyDeveloper: no, that's the quick approach.

Answer (score 3):

It will compare the items by reference.So it will only work if there is an item that has the same reference. If you wanna compare your items based on property values you should implement `IEquatable<T>` in your class.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I need to compare by values, can you show me a little more details on how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: there is already an example  [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190(v=vs.110).aspx)